# Delimiter in scanner, keep delimiters

Tags: java

I have a file like so:

```
foo|blah
bar
baz
foo|moreblah
morebar
morebaz
```

I want to split it at foo. So I've got

```
scanner.useDelimiter("foo")
```

This almost works, except that in the output I'm losing the delimiter "foo".  In other words, for the first chunk, I end up with

```
|blah
bar
baz
```

How do I keep the delimiter?

Comment: Please clarify, ideally by example: When you say “keep the delimiter”, do you mean “as a separate element” or “left at the start of the element” or “left at the end of the element”? Note that if the first option, it can be consumed and inferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split using a look ahead, which asserts that the following input is "foo" without consuming it, and consumes (unwanted) preceding line endings:

```
String[] parts = str.split("\\R*(?=foo)");
```

`\R` means “any line ending”.

FYI split won’t create a leading blank element if the first match is zero width (as here),

Answer (score 3):

Does this do it for you?  It uses zero width assertions to split around the delimeter.  So it preserves it for you.

```
String text = "foo|blah\nbar\nbaz\nfoo|moreblah\nmorebar\nmorebaz\n";
String regex = "(?<=foo)(?!foo)|(?=foo)(?!<foo)";

String[] vals = text.split(regex);
for (String v : vals) {
    System.out.println(v);
}
```

Prints

```
foo
|blah
bar
baz

foo
|moreblah
morebar
morebaz
```

Comment: I would think `(?=foo)` is enough

Comment: I was thinking generally for something like `afoobfoocfoodfooefoo`.  But if it can be improved, I'm all for it.

Comment: Using (?=foo) is working so far.  Using the full regex in the answer "works", but for some reason I end up with a CRLF after each foo.  In any case, thanks!

Comment: If you end up with a `CRLF` after each foo in the later case it is because the regex is grabbing the delimiter as a lone object.  In the case that @Bohemian suggested, it is simply splitting on `foo` but not separating it from the rest of the string while still preserving it.   It all depends on what you want.  It seems to me that @Bohemian's suggestion is the best and least complicated.